# initialize undetect_chromedriver timeout

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-poetry, undetected-chromedriver

I'm using undetected_chromedriver to scrap website. But I sometime will encounter a timeout error when initialize undetected_chromedirver instance.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uc.Chrome(debug=True)
    time.sleep(100)
```

I use poetry to manage my virtual environment. And the version of package are..

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
undetected-chromedriver = "^3.5.4"
selenium = "^4.17.2"
```

error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1286, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1332, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 979, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1458, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darren_ho/Desktop/Self_Learning/Python/Tesing_Ground/undetect_chromedriver/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    uc.Chrome(debug=True)
  File "/Users/darren_ho/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/undetect-chromedriver-ZY2ISn5B-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.patcher.auto()
  File "/Users/darren_ho/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/undetect-chromedriver-ZY2ISn5B-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/patcher.py", line 178, in auto
    self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/darren_ho/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/undetect-chromedriver-ZY2ISn5B-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/patcher.py", line 287, in fetch_package
    return urlretrieve(download_url)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>
```

I also switch my network but it seems like its not the root cause, what may be the cause that I can't initialize driver.